# How to detect the current theme of the IntelliJ via open api?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How to detect the current theme of the IntelliJ via open api (com.intellij.openapi)?

[image: Example: "Dracula"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `UIUtil.isUnderDarcula()` method.

Comment: Thanks, but where do I type that though ?

Comment: @Felix In your plugin code, whenever you want to perform this operation.